# applying a function of sqrt on a data frame

Tags: r, apply

I want to compute the following equation between each two points, i dont know how to apply that in the whole data set:

```
Point  x y z
1      4 3 8
2      8 5 4
3      5 4 7
4      2 7 4

D1,2 = sqrt((x2-x1)²+ (y2-y1)²+( z2-z1)²)
```

Comment: You should look into the `dist` function

Comment: Specifically, `dist(df[-1])`. If you want it back in a data.frame, `broom::tidy(dist(df[-1]))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be best to use `dist` for calculating the distance as suggested in the comments.

```
data.frame(as.matrix(dist(df[,-1], diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE)))
```

You could also use `sapply` to calculate the distance (or apply some other formula) by yourself

```
sapply(1:NROW(df), function(i)
    sapply(1:NROW(df), function(j)
        sqrt(diff(df$x[c(i,j)])^2 + diff(df$y[c(i,j)])^2 + diff(df$z[c(i,j)])^2)))
#         [,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]
#[1,] 0.000000 6.000000 1.732051 6.000000
#[2,] 6.000000 0.000000 4.358899 6.324555
#[3,] 1.732051 4.358899 0.000000 5.196152
#[4,] 6.000000 6.324555 5.196152 0.000000
```